# How to watch/inspect a stringlist range in Delphi IDE?

Tags: delphi, range, tstringlist

I often find myself in the situation that I am debugging what is going on in part of a stringlist,
e.g. data is being manipulated in the range StringList[StartOfBlock] to StringList[EndOfBlock].
One or more variable indexes in that range might be available that I can quickly inspect or watch, e.g. StringList[LineNum], but it is cumbersome to inspect neighbouring strings in the range StartBlock/Endblock.
I can add another watch on StringList[LineNum+1], or modify the expression in the Ctrl-F7 inspector, but that is so much work ;-(

I would love to have StringList[StartOfBlock] to StringList[EndOfBlock] in the IDE in view permanently.
(And it would be very nice if that view changes when StartOfBlock/EndOfBlock changes, or if that view can be refreshed.)

How would I build something 'into the IDE' to accomplish that?

Comment: Newer Delphi versions (I think starting from XE) can display string list content in the object inspector.

Comment: We are working in D2007. XE2 is still a few months off ;-)

Answer (score 8):

Create a global function:

```
function GetLines(AList: TStrings; AStart, AEnd: Integer): string;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  Result := '';
  for I := AStart to AEnd do
    if I < AList.Count then
      Result := Result + AList[I] + sLineBreak;
end;
```

You can watch this function:
GetLines(StringList, StartOfBlock, EndOfBlock)
but enable function execution in watch settings (Allow function calls checkbox).

Comment: You may need to ensure that the linker doesn't strip the function on account of it not being called by any function in your program

Comment: This is smart, why didn't I think of that ;-)  I indeed have to make a dummy call to the routine to prevent the linker from throwing it out. I have not yet marked this as the 'right answer' because the list is not in view and only with the mouse over the watch window do I get an ugly formatted list. It's something, but an always visible list of "[linenum] string" is the ultimate goal...

Comment: Then you have to create an always on top floating window that is listing the required lines and GetLines refreshes it's contents whenever it is called by the watch window.

Comment: But how would I do that in the IDE? any clues?

Comment: You don't do it in the IDE, you do it runtime. Your project creates a form if it is started in debug mode. And you can reach this form from GetLines function.

Comment: Than than dealing with floating windows you could send the function's result to WINDOWS.OutputDebugStr.  Or, to CodeInsight, which we've just started using and are delighted with for this sort of thing.

Comment: could use for I := AStart to Min(AEnd, AList.Count - 1) do

Answer (score 3):

For Delphi Version 2010 and up you can use debug visualizers that do exactly what you want. A TStrings visualizer is already built in. For more info look e.g. [here](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/40268)

Comment: I will remember that for when we have moved to XE2. Currently we are on Delphi 2007

Comment: It looks as if I might be able to do something with the OpenTools API (never worked with that).